# What are usual causes of problems with central locking system?

Tags: electrical, ford, focus

I have a ford focus mk1, it doesn't have a remote key, but a central locking system, ie, when some door is unlocked all should be unlocked.

It does not work at all. I have checked the central fuses, behind the glove compartment, and they seem ok, what else might it be and how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Many cars with this system don't unlock all doors until you turn the key a second time ... Have you tried this?

Comment: It used to work but now it doesn't, so that's not it, but thanks!

Comment: If it used to work and it doesn't now, wouldn't you think that's *exactly* the issue? Not that I'd know how to fix it, but I'd suspect it has something to do with the door unlocking mechanism, or possibly a fuse has burnt out.